# Clutch catches VERY low, is this bad?

Tags: clutch, peugeot

This is similar to the 'clutch catches very high' question but obviously the opposite.

It's a Peugeot 206 X reg and I have had it since 30K miles and it has run fine and I and the previous owner looked/looking after it. Basically I need my foot firm to the floor now (65K miles on the clock) otherwise I get that dreaded crunch noise you get when you don't put the clutch pedal down enough. It has always need a bit of travel when you press on the clutch pedal but I believe it used to be a bit better than this.

The clutch does not slip at all and the car runs great. Is this indicative of anything going wrong, does it just need the clutch cable replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the 206, but my old 306 (1995) had a cable clutch with a self-adjuster, and the latter quite regularly got itself out of adjustment - The trick was to undo the clutch end of the cable, which was fairly easy to get to, and give it several sharp tugs to reset the adjuster, then re-attach it and pump the pedal a few times to adjust it back into position again.

Comment: Can you give me a clue (I know it's a 306 not a 206 but still) as to roughly where I would find the 'undo the clutch end of the cable', I'm not entirely sure what I am looking for other than a cable

Comment: If I remember correctly (it was a few years ago), it was on the top of the clutch housing, towards the front. Looking from the front, slightly right-of-centre in the engine bay, under the airbox.

Comment: Try this thread: http://www.206info.co.uk/Forums/viewtopic/t=28995.html. Google suggests that it might vary according to which gearbox you have however

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an indicator of anything bad or a cable replacement needed, although worth checking while you have the car looked at.

Just an adjustment of the clutch cable length should be all that is required. It's very quick and easy to do to set it up to the height you feel comfortable with. There should be an automatic adjuster on the pedal, so this may need fixing/replacing.

As per comment - if your car has a direct hydraulic connection from the pedal, you should be able to either alter the lever arm on the pedal, or check the hydraulic pressure in the line - if it is too low you could get this symptom.

Comment: Wow, I'm not familiar with Peugeots, I didn't even know there were any cars left that still used clutch cables!

Comment: Some do, some don't - I was making a bit of an assumption that a 206 with 65k miles was old enough that it would. Will add in an update.

Comment: I haven't seen a car newer than about 1970 that didn't have a hydraulic clutch!  Must be a Europe vs. USA difference to have such new cars that have cables!